# Deserializing with DataContract Collection<Class> to derived Class

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, datacontract

The title is a bit confusing, hopefully someone maybe know's a better fitting title for my problem.

I am trying to create a class which derives from `Collection<Classname>` to implement an easy way to save and loading Configuration files. Writing to file is no problem, but I am not able to implement the deserialze function. I am unsure how to assign the deserialized content back to my instance.

Current approach:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Configurations", Namespace = "")]
public class Configurations : Collection<Configuration>
{
    internal void SerializeToBinaryFile(string path)
    {
        Helper.DumpObjectToBinaryFile(this, path);
    }

    internal void DeserializeFromBinaryFile(string path)
    {
       // Getting Error:
       // This expression can not be used as an assignment target
       this = Helper.GetObjectFromBinaryFile<Collection<Configuration>>(path);
    }
}
```

I am familiar with `this.Add([Configuration])` but this just gives the opportunity to insert **one** item. I thought about using a `foreach(Configuration c in  temporaryObject` and add them one by one but this can't be the best solution.

Thanks for any hint!

Edit 1:

I've added the foreach iteration for adding the Configurations

```
    internal void DeserializeFromBinaryFile(string path)
    {
        foreach (var c in Helper.GetObjectFromBinaryFile<Collection<Configuration>>(path))
        {
            Add(c);
        }
    }
```

This seems to work fine. Does someone know a better pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to new instance of class to "this" regardless if you are doing de-serialization or something else. Code bellow just uses new constructor and doesn't work either. Basically, you do have different 2 instances of class in memory at that point.

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public void CreatePoint(int x, int y)
    {
        // Doesn't work either
        this = new Point();
    }
}
```

You have to do this outside of the body of the class, so rather make static deserialization method:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Configurations", Namespace = "")]
public class Configurations : Collection<Configuration>
{
    internal void SerializeToBinaryFile(string path)
    {
        Helper.DumpObjectToBinaryFile(this, path);
    }

    internal static Configurations DeserializeFromBinaryFile(string path)
    {
        return Helper.GetObjectFromBinaryFile<Collection<Configuration>>(path);
    }
}
```